# How to work with the url of a fileReader object?

Tags: javascript, filereader

Hello! I'am trying to make it work a function called `loadDocument`, who need a url of the loaded files from the user local computer to work. I'm writing an API to load document from local user computer, and show it on a web reader.

This is my upload button :
  `<input type="file" id="input" onchange="module.onLoadSelection();" alt="Browse" name="upload"/>`

This is my function without fileReader :

```js
var onLoadSelection = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('input');
    if (select && select.value) {
        var id= '';
        var url = select.files.item(0).name;
        module.loadDocument(url,id);
    }
};
```

This is my function with fileReader :

```js
var loadTest = function (input) {
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    console.log("file loaded! ->", file); // i can read the obj of my file
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var id = ''; // don't need rightnow
    var url = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log("url :", url); // show me undefined....
    module.loadDocument(url,id);
}
```

What i am trying is to get the url of the loaded file from user computer to get my function loadDocument working. She need a url parameter to work.

`loadDocument` is an API function, i assume i can't get the filepath of my user due to security reason.

What do i need to change/update on my `loadDocument();` function to work?

Edit : In fact, nothing to change. The correct way to read my file was :
`<input type="file" id="input" onchange="module.onLoadSelection(this.files);" alt="Browse" name="upload"/>`

```js
var onLoadSelection = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length == 1) {
       var id = '';
       var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
       module.loadDocument(url,id);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a FileReader at all.

When you want to display a File (or a Blob) that is in the browser's memory or on user's disk, then all you need is to generate an URL that do point to this memory slot.
That's exactly what [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) does: it returns a *Blob URI* (`blob://`) that points to the data either in memory or on the disk, acting exactly as a simple pointer.

This method has various advantages over the `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` method. To name a few:

- Store the data in memory only once, when FileReader would need it at reading, then generate a copy as an base64 encoded, and an other one at displaying...
- Synchronous. Since all it does is to generate a pointer, no need to make it async.
- Cleaner code.

```js
const module = {
  loadDocument: (url) => {
    document.body.append(
      Object.assign(
        document.createElement('iframe'),
        { src: url }
      )
    )
  }
};

document.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    module.loadDocument(url);
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Kaiido, this is completly working ! I really appreciate your answer, it's helped me to understand more deeply the file managment in Javascript.
I started conding in JS 1 month ago... 
Best regards from France, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function PreviewFiles(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
             //alert(e.target.result);
                 $('#pclogo').prop('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(200)
                    .height(200);
                    var base64result = e.target.result.split(',')[1];
                $('input[name="logo"]').val(base64result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

File objects have a [`readAsDataURL` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

Use that.

```
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    doSomethingWithAUrl(reader.result);
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Quentin to lead me to the correct way of writing this function. In my case, do i need to fire my function loadDocument(url,id) in the eventlistener or use the reader instance "reader.readAsDataURL(file)" as url parameter of my function ?

Comment: @KubNetwork — Since `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` doesn't return a URL, and since I wrote `doSomethingWithAUrl` as an example function name …

Comment: No. FileReader does, File objects don't.